# How to Call a custom connector API from Power App Canvas

Tags: office365, power-automate, powerapps-canvas

I have a custom connector to create a new user as POST, I have created a new Power App canvas with user details input form fields to create a new user. How to use custom connector to send a POST request to create new user with the details entered in the canvas APP?

The online example i see are explaining to "consume" data from the custom data connector, are there any references that explain how to post data to custom connector?

Answer (score 1):

```
POST [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/accounts HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0
Accept: application/json

{
    "name": "Sample Account",
    "creditonhold": false,
    "address1_latitude": 47.639583,
    "description": "This is the description of the sample account",
    "revenue": 5000000,
    "accountcategorycode": 1
}
```

(source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/create-entity-web-api)

This shows an example of a POST request to create a new record in an entity (or a new row in a table if you're using normal industry terms). The example is how you'd build the POST endpoint in your custom connector. You just need to define the field names you want to use (not the values the example shows).

So, once your post endpoint has been added to your custom connector, you can use it in your canvas app in a button's `OnSelect`, for example. Let's say your custom connector is called CustomConnector, and your endpoint is called myPost, then you'd do something like

```
CustomConnector.myPost({
    "name": "Sample Account",
    "creditonhold": false,
    "address1_latitude": 47.639583,
    "description": "This is the description of the sample account",
    "revenue": 5000000,
    "accountcategorycode": 1
})
```

Documentation about calling a custom connector endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/use-custom-connector-powerapps#add-formulas-to-drive-behavior

Comment: It's an old answer of yours but what's `myPost` in your answer, please?

Comment: It's an example of a name you might call your API endpoint. Like if you have an API endpoint that gets a user's info with a GET request, called getUserInfo, then you'd call it like `CustomConnector.getUserInfo()`. The example above (myPost) is for a POST endpoint - and it shows an example of how you'd pass body data to the POST request from powerapps.